# Disable nginx access log using supervisor in docker

Tags: nginx, docker, supervisord

I cannot seem to disable access logs from nginx outputting on docker stdout (showing in `docker logs <container>`)

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.3.11-fpm-alpine as base

WORKDIR /var/www

# Use the default production configuration
RUN cp "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-production" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"

#Â Install dependencies
RUN set -xe \
    && apk add --no-cache bash icu-dev  \
    && apk add --no-cache nginx supervisor curl

# Configure nginx
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Configure supervisord
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

# Make sure files/folders needed by the processes are accessable when they run under the nobody user
RUN chown -R nobody.nobody /run && \
  chown -R nobody.nobody /var/lib/nginx && \
  chown -R nobody.nobody /var/tmp/nginx && \
  chown -R nobody.nobody /var/log/nginx

# Setup document root
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html/public

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN echo "<?php echo 'OK';" >> /var/www/html/public/healthcheck.php

USER nobody

# Expose the port nginx is reachable on
EXPOSE 8080

# Let supervisord start nginx & php-fpm
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf"]
```

This is the nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  1;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    access_log off;

    proxy_buffers 16 16k;
    proxy_buffer_size 16k;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen [::]:8080 default_server;
        listen 8080 default_server;
        server_name _;

        sendfile off;

        root /var/www/html/public;
        index index.php index.html;

        location = /healthcheck.php {
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    include fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }

    }
}
```

This is the supervisord.conf

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
logfile=/dev/null
logfile_maxbytes=0
pidfile=/run/supervisord.pid

[program:php-fpm]
command=php-fpm -F
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
autorestart=false
startretries=0

[program:nginx]
command=nginx -g 'daemon off;'
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
autorestart=false
startretries=0
```

but still getting output i dont want

```
2019-12-16 11:04:30,107 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2019-12-16 11:04:31,110 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 7
2019-12-16 11:04:31,122 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm' with pid 8
[16-Dec-2019 11:04:31] NOTICE: [pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[16-Dec-2019 11:04:31] NOTICE: [pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[16-Dec-2019 11:04:31] NOTICE: [pool www] 'group' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[16-Dec-2019 11:04:31] NOTICE: [pool www] 'group' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[16-Dec-2019 11:04:31] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 8
[16-Dec-2019 11:04:31] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
2019-12-16 11:04:32,209 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2019-12-16 11:04:32,211 INFO success: php-fpm entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
127.0.0.1 -  16/Dec/2019:11:04:34 +0000 "GET /healthcheck.php" 200
127.0.0.1 -  16/Dec/2019:11:04:34 +0000 "GET /healthcheck.php" 200
127.0.0.1 -  16/Dec/2019:11:04:34 +0000 "GET /healthcheck.php" 200
```

How can i disable nginx access log using Docker and supervisor ?

Comment: Have you tried something like `access_log  /dev/null;` in your nginx.conf?

Comment: @emmdee yep same thing - its almost as though `supervisord` is capturing the output before nginx config kicks in ... very strange (at least to me)

Comment: I don't want to be one of "those guys" but I have always felt that running a process manager (supervisord/etc) inside Docker isn't really using Docker as originally intended. I know a lot of guys do it but for me I have a php container, and an nginx container and they communicate using internal Docker networking. That's my two cents but it's not a solution to your given problem.

Comment: If you aren't stuck with this particular design, having php-frm and nginx in one container, you can sidestep this with a more Dockerly design. Make two containers as emmdee suggested, drop supervisod altogether and use a single-node docker swarm instead. If you can live with such a thing, I'll put an answer in here with details about how to do that so it's not a heavy lift for you just to try it out.

Comment: I also wonder if you've tried setting supervisord's config to send stdout from nginx to /dev/null?

Comment: Check if using `stdout_logfile=/dev/null` in your supervisord config makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to figure out what the issue was - it was the access log of `php-fpm` that was logging those requests and infact `nginx` wasnt logging at all. To find out what is logging what i enabled debug logging on `supervisord`, this gave me the output below

```
2020-01-06 11:57:27,790 DEBG 'php-fpm' stderr output:
127.0.0.1 -  06/Jan/2020:11:57:27 +0000 "GET /healthcheck.php" 200

2020-01-06 11:57:27,790 DEBG 'php-fpm' stderr output:
127.0.0.1 -  06/Jan/2020:11:57:27 +0000 "GET /healthcheck.php" 200

2020-01-06 11:57:27,792 DEBG 'nginx' stdout output:
172.17.0.1 - - [06/Jan/2020:11:57:27 +0000] "GET /healthcheck.php HTTP/1.1" 200 12 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0" "-"

2020-01-06 11:57:27,792 DEBG 'nginx' stdout output:
172.17.0.1 - - [06/Jan/2020:11:57:27 +0000] "GET /healthcheck.php HTTP/1.1" 200 12 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0" "-"
```

I then updated the config (as by default the `php-fpm` docker image outputs access log to `stdout`) and the config for `nginx` started working as expected